# Define Google Maps marker icons with zoom dependent size

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When defining custom icon for markers in the Google Maps API then the size of the icon is kept the same, independent of the zoom level.

Is it possible to set a property, that not only the map is enlarged, but also the image when zooming to it?

If this is not possible, is there an alternative way of achieving this? Maybe simply setting an image at the point of the marker instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it through CSS. Most of the times, the markers are drawn directly on the canvas.

With JS, you would save a reference to all you markers, then on zoom you loop through all your markers:

```
 markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    var icon = new google.maps.Icon({
                      url:        'yourMarkerIconURL',
                      size:       'yourSize',
                      scaledSize: 'scaledSize'
                   })
    marker.setIcon(icon)
 })
```

You want to use either `scaledSize` or `size` to control the size of the markers icon.